# How sort json array multiple times in swift

Tags: mysql, json, swift, sorting

I am trying to sort an array by a few values, not just one but three I can sort it like this

```
mysocialArray.sort({$0["date"] > $1["date"]})
```

This works fine, but i can find any where how to then sort it again so i get them sorted on time and another sort. SO should sort three times. When i just add another sort it is not taking the date into account.

The sorted json output will then be loaded in arrays  as strings to display on the viewcontroller

How should I solve this?

thanks

Comment: You're saying you need to sort on one value, then when they are equal, it should sort on another value in the array?

Comment: no that is not what i want to do. I want to sort it on date, time and if the post has been read, which is a string that says yes or no. So when it sorted first on date, then the sorted array has to be sorted on time but keep  the date in mind. After that another sort This way the latest post that not yet have been read are at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your requirements of "This way the latest post that not yet have been read are at the top", looks like you are looking to sort by multiple criteria. I typed this in the dark so you may have to adjust it to fit your case:

```
mySocialArray.sort {
    // First sort by read status. Assuming read is of type Bool
    let (read1, read2) = ($0["read"] ? 1 : 0, $1["read"] ? 1 : 0)
    if read1 != read2 {
        return read1 > read2
    }

    // Then short by date. I assume date is of type NSDate
    let (date1, date2) = ($0["date"], $1["date"])
    if date1.timeIntervalSince1970 != date2.timeIntervalSince1970 {
        return date1 > date2
    }

    // And lastly sort by time
    return $0["time"] > $1["time"]
}
```

Comment: thank that is working like a charm. No i understand how it is being doing and the flow of it.